# Flexbox containing h3 and section using space-between not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari, cross-browser

I'm using the `<details>` html tag for an expandable content area with a heading, but I am wanting to style the `<summary>` part like other clickable elements on the site. Here's the skeleton of the markup:

```
<details aria-expanded="false">
  <summary>
    <h3>Expandable</h3>
    <section>
      <svg>...</svg>
    </section>
  </summary>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</details>
```

My CSS styles the `<summary>` as a flex container with `justify-content: space-between` so that the `<h3>` appears on the left and the `<svg>` appears on the right. This works as desired in all browsers (even ie11) apart from Safari. Here's the CSS:

```
summary {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  list-style: none; /* for ff */
  padding: 2em;
} 
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none; /* for safari */
}
```

The issue lies with the fact that safari is giving the `<h3>` the width of the container and the `<section>` is also given 100%. No other browser handles it this way.

Here's what it's supposed to look like:
[image]

Here's what it looks like on safari: [image]

Comment: Reverse the h3/svg. Make svg float and reset svg order. It might be a workaround if safari refuses to reset summary  display.

Comment: On IOS safari browser summary isn't supported [https://caniuse.com/#search=summary](https://caniuse.com/#search=summary)